# print original line numbers of extracted range with cat and sed

Tags: sed, cat

I'm extracting lines `8` through `11` from a file (`example.c`),
and I want the lines to be numbered `8,9,10,11`.
Here's what I tried, but (unsurprisingly) it gives me the line numbers
`1,2,3,4`. There's got to be a simple way around this, right?

```
$ sed -n '8,11p;12q' example.c | cat -n
     1      x = 5;
     2      y = 6;
     3      z = 7;
     4      w = 8;
```

And here's my `example.c` file for completeness:

```
$ cat -n example.c
     1  int x;
     2  int y;
     3  int z;
     4  int w;
     5  
     6  int main()
     7  {
     8      x = 5;
     9      y = 6;
    10      z = 7;
    11      w = 8;
    12  
    13      return x+y+z+w;
    14  }
```

Comment: `cat -n example.c | sed -n '8,11p;12q'`?

Comment: D'oh! sorry for missing that!

Comment: Or `awk 'NR >= 8 { print NR, $0 } NR==11 { exit }' example.c`